# .net mvc form login url redirecting

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership

net mvc 3 application.

I have an issue with the login form.

When I try to log with my admin user there is no issue logs in the first time but if I try to login with any other issue i have to login trhough the second login page.

first form ur is this:

http://HOST.com/Login/Login

with any other use except for my db admin user I have to try one time then get this url

http://HOST.com/Login/Login?ReturnUrl=%2f

redirect and try again, then it logs in properly. Happens every single time.

this is my form code for form section in my web.config

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="Login/Login" timeout="200000" slidingExpiration="true">
  </forms>
</authentication>

    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
```

Thank you for any suggestions

login form file:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Security;
using SAMPLE.Models;
using SAMPLE.Helpers;
using System.Web;
using System.Linq;
namespace SAMPLE.Controllers
{
    public class LoginController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Login(string username, string password, string returnUrl)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(username) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                if (UserAccount.IsValid(username, password))
                    RedirectFromLoginPage(username, returnUrl);
                else
                    ViewData["LoginMessage"] = "Incorrect username or password.";
            }

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
        }
        private void RedirectFromLoginPage(string username, string returnUrl)
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(username, false);

            var userType = 0;
            var user =  UserAccount.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == username.ToLower());
            if(user!=null)
             userType = user.UserType;             

            if (userType == 2)
            {
                Response.Redirect("/Usrmgmt");
            }
            else
            {
                var privileges = SAMPLE.Helpers.SAMPLEContext.Privileges;

                if ((privileges & PrivilegeConstants.Home) == PrivilegeConstants.Home)
                    Response.Redirect("/");
                else if ((privileges & PrivilegeConstants.Budgets) == PrivilegeConstants.Budgets)
                    Response.Redirect("/Budget");

                else if ((privileges & PrivilegeConstants.Estimates) == PrivilegeConstants.Estimates)
                    Response.Redirect("/Estimate");

                else if ((privileges & PrivilegeConstants.EstimageCatalogue) == PrivilegeConstants.EstimageCatalogue)
                    Response.Redirect("/Labour");

                else if ((privileges & PrivilegeConstants.CRM) == PrivilegeConstants.CRM)
                    Response.Redirect("/CRM");

                else if ((privileges & PrivilegeConstants.JobStatus) == PrivilegeConstants.JobStatus)
                    Response.Redirect("/JobStatus");  

                else if ((privileges & PrivilegeConstants.UserManage) == PrivilegeConstants.UserManage)
                    Response.Redirect("/Administration");

                else
                    Response.Redirect("/");
            }
            //}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the way it works: I have a user and pass I use that takes me to the /ursmgmt page. This page is my super admin page. I Create companies in here. When I create a new company I create an admin for that company. so then the company uses that login information and logs into their application and can set up extra users in their "user administration page".

Comment: The user I created as a super admin and also any other users the company creates for their company have user type=0. The first user I create / company admin doesnt have any privileges. Privileges are setup after by the company admin in their user administration page. so works like this just to make sure I am clear: 1) I log with user "admin" password: "admin" this takes me to the super admin company creation page

Comment: 2) I create a new company called A1Company and set up the admin user for that company as A1CompanyAdmin. 3) A1CompanyAdmin logs into the application and goes to the user management page and creates a new user "A1CompanySalesUser" then gives privileges ( check marks to which pages out of the 5 pages the user can access. so just clicks on one or all pages. The A1CompanySalesUser and A1CompanyAdmin both have user type=0 could it be an issue with the user type or privileges?

Answer (score 1):

Please change your web.config to:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="~/Login/Login" timeout="2880" protection="All"/>
</authentication>
```

Remove the code below and try again:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: what is the difference with protection=all and sliding expiration? I was trying that as I was experiencing constant session timeouts where I would be sent back to the login page. This was happening before I added any sessiontimout. From what I learned until today if no sessionatimeout line is there the default is 30 min but even then I was getting logged out way before this 30 mins,

Comment: protection=all means all your pages are protected by the form authentication. While sliding expiration resets the expiration time for a valid authentication cookie if a request is made and more than half of the timeout interval has elapsed.

Comment: I replaced my code in the web.config as you suggested. Still have the same issue. Some more background: the application I am using is setup for multiple users, each user/company is allowed to add up their users, the extra company users are connected to each company. As of right now I have 2 users who are setup as admins for the db. If I try to log in with any of those direct users I can access the application in the first try. I have the issue is with the users that were created by one of the "companies"

Comment: Just to make it clear I access the application with user admin this takes me to a master company/user setup screen. So for example i create a user called "CompanyA" this becomes the admin user for companyA and when they enter in the application can log into their user admin page and create other users. so lets say CompanyA logs in and creates "CompanyAuser1"  If log out and try the CompanyA admin user logs me in the first time, but if i use the CompanyAuser1 I created after this is the one that redirects me to the new page and after the second try I can log in.

Comment: code pasted, the user I am having an issue has user type= 0 I can set privileges for users but privileges is pretty simple just allows or not allow access to the 5 main menus I have.

Comment: What is UserAccount? Did you used Membership.ValidateUser? You should also call FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie after the validation successed

Comment: so where should I add the missing line? after what line? I am not the developer so just trying to get some information for tomorrow when I meet again with the developer. Thank you